# How to create camera which has nigth vision capacity

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to create a night vision camera app, I have already created a custom 
camera, but to support a night vision I have no clue from where to start.

Is there any libraries available for night vision effect ?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're trying to create an app that takes a daylight image and makes it *look* light a night vision capture, not actually turn a regular mobile device into a night-vision camera?

Comment: No, I actually want to enable the night vision, while capturing image in dark light.